# Bluetooth heart rate/blood pressure monitor

Tags: bluetooth, heart-rate-monitors

I am trying to find a wristband type device that will measure heart rate and blood pressure and transmit using Bluetooth to a PC. There are many devices, but all talk to a smart phone.

But, I want to read the data on a PC preferably in C# or Matlab. I am going to use a USB Bluetooth dongle. However the trouble is that the heart rate/blood pressure monitor vendors are not so forthcoming regarding the precise messaging protocol details. So it's going to be a bit of trial and error in device selection.

I just wanted to know if any of you have done something like this and if so is there a device that you can recommend. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the Bluetooth SIG? The spec for the Blood Pressure Profile & Service are available for download here https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need anything hardware side. The service for HRM should be well defined in the Bluetooth spec for any device that supports it. Mbed even has examples using it.

Answer (score 0):

We have done similar things, but we have not used any ready made dongle to interface it with PC.. Instead of that We have made our custom scanner device with nRF52, which scans HRM device and get the data and dumped data serially to the PC and then PC processed that data.

You can buy nRF52 kit, in which they have the HRM examples. You can try that, if you are facing any problem, you can contact me.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site!  This is interesting, but are you affiliated with this project?  If so, we require that you [fully disclose that affiliation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/333472) Also, try to stick to concrete answers that require no clarification from the author, until you reach [50 reputation](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and can comment.  Thanks!